# LC VCO sub 30nm node circuit and layout design

Tags: oscillator, passive-networks, layout, pll, vco

I am working on an LC VCO in a sub 30nm node to oscillate between 3 to 6 GHz. Here are the things I did so far:

1. I already have the layout and extracted netlist for the integrated coil, L.
2. So I did AC analysis simulation of the coil with ideal cap and current source of 1 A to determine the parallel resistance, \$R_p\$ at 3 GHz resonance. (This is with assumption that the inductor Q value will increase with frequency). I got \$R_p = 43 \Omega\$ which is the peak value I got.
3. From equations I get \$2<g_mR_p\$. I put some margin and set \$g_m = 50\text{ mS}\$. But, the oscillations are dying out.
4. Next, I set \$g_m = 160\text{ mS}\$ (randomly set) and I get oscillations.

[image]

Why is my \$g_m\$ calculation is off? How do I determine the optimum value of \$g_m\$?

Let me know if there is mistake(s) in my approach of the design.

Also, please let me know the hspice circuit to test the VCO design.

Everything here is ideal except the coil. I replaced the actual extracted coil in place of my ideal one in the circuit.

I'm hoping to figure out the sizes of the transistor devices before worrying about the layout challenges beyond that.

Comment: Your approach looks OK to me. Did you determine that peak impedance **excluding the MOSFETs** (only L and C) ? And by looking at the magnitude only? I like to also plot the **Real** part of the impedance as well: Re(Z) but that should give the same value.

Comment: I forgot to mention: 

Everything here is ideal except the coil. I replaced the actual extracted coil in place of my ideal one in the circuit.

I first need to figure out the sizes of the transistor devices before worrying about the layout challenges beyond that..

Also, yeah, I determined the peak impedance with **only L and C.**

Can you tell me how to do this: I like to also plot the Real part of the impedance as well: Re(Z) but that should give the same value?